# Unable to share PHP variable

Tags: php, variables

I am having trouble sharing a variable value between my main body of code and as function.

For this example, I want to upload an image to the DB with a value which matches the ID of the Place being used.

I currently grab the ID of the place being used from the URL using `$_REQUEST` and am attempting to write that to a variable 'mid' which I then send to the `createthumnail` function (contained in **functions2.php**), but the ***'mid'*** value will not transfer for some reason.

To recreate:

1. Go to: http://www.students.bl.rdi.co.uk/stu26984/index.php
2. Login with: Username: Test Password: test123
3. Go to My Places
4. Click on WalkaboutSF link
5. Attempt to upload a file via the 'Choose File' button

Below is the full text of functions2.php

```
<?php

function createThumbnail2($filename, $mid) {
    include 'base.php';
    require 'config.php';
    if(preg_match('/[.](jpg)$/', $filename)) {
        $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($path_to_image_directory . $filename);
    } else if (preg_match('/[.](gif)$/', $filename)) {
        $im = imagecreatefromgif($path_to_image_directory . $filename);
    } else if (preg_match('/[.](png)$/', $filename)) {
        $im = imagecreatefrompng($path_to_image_directory . $filename);
    }

    $ox = imagesx($im);
    $oy = imagesy($im);

    $nx = $final_width_of_image;
    $ny = floor($oy * ($final_width_of_image / $ox));

    $nm = imagecreatetruecolor($nx, $ny);

    imagecopyresized($nm, $im, 0,0,0,0,$nx,$ny,$ox,$oy);

    if(!file_exists($path_to_thumbs_directory)) {
      if(!mkdir($path_to_thumbs_directory)) {
           die("There was a problem. Please try again!");
      } 
       }

    imagejpeg($nm, $path_to_thumbs_directory . $filename);
    //  $cookieUserx=$_SESSION['Username'];
    //  $checkCustidx=mysql_query("SELECT custid AS id from customers WHERE custUsername='".$cookieUserx."';");
    //  $rx=mysql_fetch_array($checkCustidx);
    //  $custidx=$rx['id'];
    //  $updateimage = mysql_query("UPDATE photos SET name = '".$filename."';")or die ('SQL Error: ' . mysql_error()); 
        $updateimage = mysql_query("INSERT INTO photos (NAME, markerid) VALUES('".$filename."', '".$mid."');")or die ('SQL Error: ' . mysql_error()); 
                   if($updateimage)  
            {  
                header("Location: /WalkaboutSF/viewplace.php?place_id=%20".$mid."");
            }  
            else  
            {  
                echo "<h1>Error</h1>";  
            }  

    $tn = '<img src="' . $path_to_thumbs_directory . $filename . '" alt="image" />';
    echo $tn;
}


?>
```

also here is the code that calls that, from:

http://www.students.bl.rdi.co.uk/stu26984/viewplace.php?place_id=%20133

```
           <div id="insertphoto">      
            <?php
    require 'config.php';
    require 'functions2.php';
    $place_id = $_REQUEST['place_id'];
            $view_place2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM markers WHERE id = '$place_id'");
            $place2 = mysql_fetch_array($view_place2);
            $mid= $place2['id'];
            echo $mid;

        if(isset($_FILES['fupload'])) {

        if(preg_match('/[.](jpg)|(gif)|(png)$/', $_FILES['fupload']['name'])) {
            $filename = $_FILES['fupload']['name'];
            $source = $_FILES['fupload']['tmp_name'];   
            $target = $path_to_image_directory . $filename;

        move_uploaded_file($source, $target);
        createThumbnail2($filename, $mid);      
    }
}
   ?>
    <h2>Add Photo</h2>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php print $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
        <input type="file" name="fupload" />
        <input type="submit" value="Go!" />
    </form>   
            </div>
```

Comment: did you try to print `$mid` out in your function? What was in it?

Comment: You may want to look into [`pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) for file extensions. A lot cleaner than using `preg_match`

Comment: I put an echo on this page, the value is '3'

http://www.students.bl.rdi.co.uk/stu26984/viewplace.php?place_id=%203

Comment: I now tried to echo the 'mid variable' instead of reloading the page, but I can see it is empty within the function, even though it looks to me like I am sending it.

Comment: You haven't included the code that actually has the problem - can we see the code where you actually call that function?

Comment: Have you tested your query in phpMyAdmin?  Have you checked that you're actually receiving the value in the URL (btw, you really should be using $_GET for that)?  Your code is in dire need of error handling.  If you code defensively, things like this either won't happen or won't be mysterious.

Comment: I do need error handling, you're right, I've just been steaming ahead with out it. The SQL seems to be fine, the photo name is being stored in the DB it's just I can't get the $mid value to transfer to the createThumbnails2 function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things that could be going on. Firstly:

```
$place2 = mysql_fetch_array($view_place2);
$mid= $place2['id'];
echo $mid;
```

Are you certain that `$mid` is being set here? Is it possible that the query returned no rows?

If you're sure it has a value here, then check this:

```
function createThumbnail2($filename, $mid) {
    include 'base.php';
    require 'config.php';
```

Are you sure that `base.php` or `config.php` are not overwriting the value of `$mid`? Try changing the code to this:

```
function createThumbnail2($filename, $mid) {
    echo "mid before includes = $mid<br />\n";
    include 'base.php';
    require 'config.php';
    echo "mid after includes = $mid<br />\n";
```

That will show you if your includes are stomping on your local variables.

**edit:** I didn't want to sidetrack the question, but your code is open to SQL injection. I could easily wipe your database by calling `viewplace.php` with a bad value. At the very least, do this:

```
$place_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['place_id']);
```

Your insert statement has the same issue. Look into using `mysqli` or `PDO` with prepared statements.

**edit 2:** The reason your code is not working is because there are 2 different HTTP requests working here: one to show the initial page and one to handle the POST to the upload form.

The issue is with the second request (the POST). This code is to blame:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php print $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
```

This is NOT passing the ID in `$_REQUEST['place_id']`. Just add this line below that one:

```
<input type="hidden" name="place_id" value=<?php echo HtmlspecialChars($_REQUEST['place_id']); ?>" />
```

This will pass the `place_id` to the second request, when the form is submitted.

Comment: Addslashes?  Really?  MySQL_real_escape_string is the way to go there if they're not going to use MySQLi or PDO

Comment: Thanks Cal, but still no luck.

Comment: Assuming the database is either Latin-1 or UTF-8, it makes absolutely no difference. There's far more wrong with this code than just escaping that variable.

Comment: @MarkHarrison - what happened?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will look into strengthening everything once I get it working. With regard to your other comments:

http://www.students.bl.rdi.co.uk/stu26984/viewplace.php?place_id=%203

On this page you can see a '3' below the longitude, this is the output of the $mid variable at that point. 

When my code then jumps to the functions2.php file to run the createThumbnail2 function $mid seems to have no value. I tried putting in the echos in you suggested but it seems like when the code gets to the createThumbnail2 function $mid is empty.

Comment: Try putting an `echo` just before the call to the function and as then first line inside the function.

Comment: I've put a few echo's in but it just shows that $mids value is not being sent to the function. If you login with the Test username and test123 password you can see mid being displayed here: http://www.students.bl.rdi.co.uk/stu26984/viewplace.php?place_id=%20133

Comment: Updated answer with a probable solution.